# two different $http get methods under one controller

Tags: angularjs, http, methods, get

I'm making my single page app and I need to call two different $http get methods under one controller. The two different $http methods are also for different pages on my app. Can I possibly do this?How? I'm using angularjs btw. Thanks for any help. It's highly appreciated

Comment: Of course you can do that .. create two functions and in both functions call your http method..

Comment: @Nirvana is this initialization correct? .constant("setting", "set.php?cmd=cgi_set", "time", "time.php?cmd=cgi_get_time")
        .controller("settingCtrl", function ($scope, $http, setting, time) {

Comment: Add any code snippets to your question, not in the comments :)

Comment: I'll strongly suggest that you create a data access layer (an angular service is a good idea), which handles all those http requests. This will make your controller clutter-free and your logic easier to test.

Comment: Thanks @boyomarinov ! :D but if it is not too much for you can you give me a sample of data access layer or angular service using my plunker above? It's okay if you don't want to.

Comment: hey, @bleykFaust, can't seem to find your plnkr, did you edit the question? If you repost your example, I might be able to help you.

Comment: @boyomarinov here's my plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/SCTo7R6xjitNvtS3H1Lb?p=preview